# Are there any known variants of this tabletop game?

Tags: labyrinth

This paper-and-pencil [game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(paper-and-pencil_game)) is said to be published in 1993, although it is known to be played by tech students since early 80's.
*Terra Incognita* tabletop game is believed to stem from it.

The game is played by at least 1 player and 1 host. First, a map of the world is created by a host, or generated by a computer. The map consists of at least one floor, surrounded by unbreakable (solid, or 'capital') walls everywhere except the entrances. At least one entrance must exist not blocked by any type of wall, and reachable and traversable both from outside and inside of the map. The map consists of square cells, or tiles. There are 6 directions the player can choose to go on his turn. The game is turn-based. He can choose to either go north, south, west, east, up or down. Vertical directions are only available when standing on stairs. The player may also choose to skip his turn. In that case, he either remains in place or teleports further by the 'well' system (see below). There are different types of tiles available, which apply different effects on the player.

The very basic tile is the solid ground, or empty tile. It does nothing and is the safest one. It also contains nothing, except for the cases when players have dropped anything in it, or when a player was killed on it. There are also rivers, river mouths, wells, chasms and bases and stairs.

Rivers move the player two tiles ahead against his will every time he enters it, until he reaches the river mouth. The player may opt to move backwards by the river, but the actual move will not take action. Moving further ahead by the river is allowed and doable. If the player opts to skip his turn while in the river, it counts as first entering it (falling inside) and moves him by 2 more cells along the current. River mouths are tiles which do not move you anymore, but you can only escape the mouth by moving sideways. Climbing out from the mouth along the current is allowed, but will not take action.
Wells are teleports. Entering the well moves you to the next well of that *system*. There can be multiple well systems on the map. The last well in the system returns you to the first.
Chasms move the player one floor below. There can be another chasm underneath the first one. Therefore, the player cannot know how many floor did he fell through. All chasms must have a "foundation" tile underneath it. One-floor maps do not have any chasms or foundations (also called *bases*).

Tiles can be divided by walls. There are solid walls, and breakable ones. Walls cannot divide the rivers. A *breakable* wall turns into a *broken* one after someone demolishes it. Players do not know where the walls are located until they try to cross them.

Players are allowed to make notes as for the map discovered so far, but are not allowed to share their map fragments. Most rivers, wells and chasms will bring ambiguity as to the player's whereabouts, therefore, he has to make notes and try to discover the correct topology by revisiting it.

The goal of the game is to find the treasure (the only tile on entire map which has this attribute) and escape the labyrinth. When playing with more than 1 player, others will try to locate you and shot you to death, trying to steal the treasure from you.  All players are aware of each other's moves and the host's responses. Therefore, you usually keep notes not only of your moves, but also try deducing the map from other's moves as well.

There are 3 special type of tiles which grant you resources: mine arsenal, ammunition, and medkit. Each player can carry up to 3 mines, 5 bullets, and has 3 health points. Mines are used to demolish breakable walls. Shots may be performed in any of the 4 directions. And health is completely regenerated when standing on medkit.

The game ends when one of the players have successfully reached the exit carrying the treasure with him. The typical map size is 10x10x3, meaning there are 3 floors, 10 by 10 tiles each, plus the entrance tiles which are outside the map area.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but the children game "Magic Labyrinth" presents a labyrinth with hidden walls under the board; each player's pawn has a magnet, and is associated with a metal ball under the board. When a player hits a wall while moving, they lose their metal ball and everyone learns that a wall was there.

Answer (score 4):

**Labyrinth** was first played in the Soviet Union in the 1970s, and like a lot of pen and paper games has a pretty loosely defined rule-set.

Probably the first codified version of the game was published in Yunyi Tekhnik (*Young Technician*) in 1993's second issue, where it was called "Iskateli kladov" (*Treasure Hunters*), this version has been simplified for children and only includes a single floor.

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(paper-and-pencil_game)) linked in the question actually has a link to another variant in it's *External links* section, termed [Labyrinth for 2](https://thejam.ru/igry-na-bumage/labirint-dlya-dvux-igrokov.html) by the author.
Again this variant is designed to be simpler and quicker with only two floors, and no indestructible walls.